# Phonegap - How to encrypt data transfer between server and device

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Using phonegap to develop an application, **which is the best way to encrypt the communication between server and application?**

E.g. Submitting forms on the Login page, Registration page

**Back end : PHP

front end : Jquery HTML5 / Phonegap
JSON Response**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use SSL communication between client and server. Check this plugin:https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP

Comment: while posting the data can i simply post as plain text ?? ex: username password ??

Comment: "SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is a standard security technology for establishing an encrypted link between a server and a client.[...]SSL allows sensitive information such as credit card numbers, social security numbers, and login credentials to be transmitted securely." [https://www.digicert.com/ssl.htm] So, if you use this kind of communication, the protocol will encrypt sensitive date for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure the connection is over SSL layer. So not HTTP but HTTPS. If it is sent over HTTPS the connection would be encrypted by design, so you can send plain data like username, password securely. If it was just HTTP, your connection would be vulnerable to man in the middle attack, so anyone between your device and server could potentially steal the sensitive data.
So what you need to do is setup HTTPS web server for the backend application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're POSTing login, registration, etc forms to the server, send the POST requests over [https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS), rather than http.

It's the protocol for secure data transmission on the web. Your phonegap app is wrapping a web application, so this is the natural way to do it.